# MultipleChatUser XMPP asmack join

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire, asmack

I am new to this OpenFire and asmack, i want the user to have a functionality of Multi Users Chatting so i searched around and i found MUC i have implemented this for creating a room and sending invitation to other users these works, other user receives the invitation but the other user is not able to join the room.

I am doing this on other user invitation receiving

Here connection is the connection of this user and room is the room name that we getting in invitation.

**MultiUserChat muc3 = new MultiUserChat(connection,room);**

**muc3.join("testbot3");**

testbot3 is just some random name.

**But this throws 404 error.**

Do i need to join the user before sending the invitation i.e if A user sending invitation to B , before invitation sent do A needs to join these users by default to room and then it depends on B to decline or just keep quite.

What i am doing is B receives invitation from A in that InvitationListner of B i am trying to join with the above code.

I have been trying for long now i am not sure what is going wrong, some one can give a sample code of how to do this it would be great help for me.

Thanks

Here is more information on my issue

As i go and check on Openfire i can see the room created by the user and he has been added himself as an owner so i dont think so it would be an issue with room getting created.

***May be this can be an issue with room getting locked, as i have read through the room is locked when the room is not completely created , i guess this is an issue with form filling when we create the room, i am not filling in the password in the form can this be an issue ?***

**Please see the following code below inside the handler i am calling a method "checkInvitation" which does the same as above code posted still i get 404. Can you please tell me what i wrong in my code.**

Do the nickname that needs to be added can be anything or it needs to something user specific ?

public void createChatroom(){

```
    MultiUserChat muc = null;

    try {
      muc = new MultiUserChat(connection, "myroom@conference.localhost");
      muc.create("testbot");

      // Get the the room's configuration form
      Form form = muc.getConfigurationForm();
      // Create a new form to submit based on the original form
      Form submitForm = form.createAnswerForm();
      // Add default answers to the form to submit
      for (Iterator fields = form.getFields(); fields.hasNext();) {
          FormField field = (FormField) fields.next();
          if (!FormField.TYPE_HIDDEN.equals(field.getType()) && field.getVariable() != null) {
              // Sets the default value as the answer
              submitForm.setDefaultAnswer(field.getVariable());
          }
      }
      // Sets the new owner of the room
      List owners = new ArrayList();
      owners.add("admin@localhost");
      submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomowners", owners);
      // Send the completed form (with default values) to the server to configure the room
      muc.sendConfigurationForm(submitForm);
      muc.join("d");

      muc.invite("b@localhost", "Meet me in this excellent room");

      muc.addInvitationRejectionListener(new InvitationRejectionListener() {
          public void invitationDeclined(String invitee, String reason) {
              // Do whatever you need here...
              System.out.println("Initee "+invitee+" reason"+reason);
          }
      });

    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    public void setConnection(XMPPConnection connection) {
    this.connection = connection;
    if (connection != null) {
        // Add a packet listener to get messages sent to us
        PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
        connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                Message message = (Message) packet;
                if (message.getBody() != null) {
                    String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message
                            .getFrom());
                    Log.i("XMPPClient", "Got text [" + message.getBody()
                            + "] from [" + fromName + "]");
                    messages.add(fromName + ":");
                    messages.add(message.getBody());
                    // Add the incoming message to the list view
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            setListAdapter();
                            checkInvitation();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }, filter);


        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                checkInvitation();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Doniv I was able to send messages to a user in a room and the processPacket method is called everytime when i send a message but i am not recieving any message in processPacket method is there any issue or we need to set any other listeners ???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 404 error indicates that:

```
404 error can occur if the room does not exist or is locked
```

So, ensure that your room is not locked or existed! The code below is how I join the room when there's an in-comming invitation:

```
private void setChatRoomInvitationListener() {
    MultiUserChat.addInvitationListener(mXmppConnection,
            new InvitationListener() {

                @Override
                public void invitationReceived(Connection connection,
                        String room, String inviter, String reason,
                        String unKnown, Message message) {

                    //MultiUserChat.decline(mXmppConnection, room, inviter,
                        //  "Don't bother me right now");
                    // MultiUserChat.decline(mXmppConnection, room, inviter,
                    // "Don't bother me right now");
                    try {
                       muc.join("test-nick-name");
                       Log.e("abc","join room successfully");
                       muc.sendMessage("I joined this room!! Bravo!!");
                    } catch (XMPPException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                       Log.e("abc","join room failed!");
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Hope this helps your error!

**Edit:**this is how I config the room:

```
 /*
         * Create room
         */
        muc.create(roomName);

        // muc.sendConfigurationForm(new Form(Form.TYPE_SUBMIT));
        Form form = muc.getConfigurationForm();
        Form submitForm = form.createAnswerForm();

        for (Iterator fields = form.getFields(); fields.hasNext();) {
            FormField field = (FormField) fields.next();
            if (!FormField.TYPE_HIDDEN.equals(field.getType())
                    && field.getVariable() != null) {
                show("field: " + field.getVariable());
                // Sets the default value as the answer
                submitForm.setDefaultAnswer(field.getVariable());
            }
        }

        List<String> owners = new ArrayList<String>();
        owners.add(DataConfig.USERNAME + "@" + DataConfig.SERVICE);
        submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomowners", owners);
        submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomname", roomName);
        submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_persistentroom", true);

        muc.sendConfigurationForm(submitForm);
        // submitForm.
        show("created room!");
        muc.addMessageListener(new PacketListener() {
            @Override
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                show(packet.toXML());
                Message mess = (Message) packet;
                showMessageToUI(mess.getFrom() + ": " + mess.getBody());
            }
        });
```

With this cofiguration, I can join a room easily without password.

Comment: As i go and check on Openfire i can see the room created by the user and he has been added himself as an owner so i dont think so it would be an issue with getting created.

Comment: Do you ever try to join the room with the user account which is  not the room's owner?

Comment: Hi @Kingfisher I was able to send messages to a user in a room and the processPacket method is called everytime when i send a message but i am not recieving any message in processPacket method is there any issue or we need to set any other listeners ???

Comment: @KK_07k11A0585 I think that you should register an listener in your `XmppConnection` object: `xmppConnection.addPacketListener(packetListener, null);` and in the `packetListener` you can check type of your received packet as like this one: `if (packet instanceof org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message
                    && ((org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message) packet)
                            .getType().equals(Type.groupchat)) `. Don't register in `MUC`, just register with your `connection`.

Comment: I have one doubt! After joining the room without specifying any **DiscussionHistory** ie using the method **muc.join(nickName);** i am  getting the chat history in **processPacket()** method. But i find that it is not giving all the messages in the group chat i want the discussion history right from the very first message in the chat to the recent message. Is there any way to acheive this ??

Comment: @KK_07k11A0585: You should read this link carefully: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#registrar-formtype-owner. When config a room, there's a field: ` <field
      var='muc#maxhistoryfetch'
      type='text-single'
      label='Maximum Number of History Messages Returned by Room'/>`.
You have to config it to receive all history messages!
P/s: next time, please ask another question!

Comment: Thanks a lot.. you really saved my day.. It worksss for creating persistant chat room

Comment: @Kingfisher can you please tell me in your  in-comming invitation  code "muc.join("test-nick-name");"from where are you taking muc object??

Comment: Ok i got it  i have to add  MultiUserChat muc=new MultiUserChat(connection, room) in  invitationReceived(Connection connection,String room, String inviter, String reason,String unKnown, Message message) in order to get muc object,thanks for the code !!!

Answer (score 0):

You may use the code snippet to join the chat:

```
public void joinMultiUserChatRoom(String userName, String roomName) {
        // Get the MultiUserChatManager
        MultiUserChatManager manager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);

        // Create a MultiUserChat using an XMPPConnection for a room
        MultiUserChat multiUserChat = manager.getMultiUserChat(roomName + "@conference.localhost");

        DiscussionHistory history = new DiscussionHistory();
        history.setMaxStanzas(-1);
        try {
            multiUserChat.join(userName, "", history, connection.getPacketReplyTimeout());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Invite a friend:

```
 /**
     * Invites another user to this room.
     *
     * @param userAddress the address of the user to invite to the room.(one
     *   may also invite users not on their contact list).
     * @param reason a reason, subject, or welcome message that would tell
     *   the the user why they are being invited.
     */
    public void invite(String userAddress, String reason)
    {
        multiUserChat.invite(userAddress, reason);
    }
```